# Why is tcpdump not capturing TLS packets on port 443?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tcpdump

I am using the following command:

```
sudo tcpdump -vvv -A -XX -i any -w dump.pcap
```

I can see several TCP packets coming or and going to the expected IP addresses on port 443. Nevertheless, I am not able to see the TLS packets sent during the SSL Handshake process. What am I missing?

Comment: What makes you think you don't see the SSL Handshake?

Comment: what is your version of tcpdump?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I am expecting to see TLS packets like Hello Client or Certificate requests but I am only seeing TCP Packets.

Comment: @A.B tcpdump version 4.9.2, libpcap version 1.7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016.

Comment: ok. until 4.0.0 the snaplen was ~ 68 bytes, but now it defaults to 256k (so that shouldn't be that).

Comment: tcpdump will only show TCP packets. It doesn't decode TLS packets like Hello Client or Certificate